# Etymology of "harren" (wait or await in English)

Tags: etymology

I am trying to find the etymology of `harren` (`to wait` or `await`). Are there any cognates in English/Dutch/Scandinavian ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ich zitierte aus Band 7 des Duden (Herkunftswörterbuch):

> **harren**: Die Herkunft des erst seit mhd. Zeit bezeugten Verbs (mhd: *harren*) ist dunkel. Das einfache Verb ist heute fast ausgestorben. Gebräuchlich sind dagegen die Zusammensetzungen und Präfixbildungen **ausharren** »geduldig warten, aushalten«, **verharren** »sich nicht von der Stelle rühren, in einem Zustand bleiben« und **beharren** »auf etwas bestehen, an etwas festhalten«.

(mhd = mittelhochdeutsch)

I try it in English:

> The etymology of "harren" is unclear. It is only attested since Middle High German. The simple verb is nearly died out. In use are only the prefix-compounds **ausharren** (to persevere), **verharren** (to remain) and **beharren** (to insist).

Comment: The prefix compounds deliver one possible cognate in Dutch: volharden which means to persevere.